# belongsTo throwing Trying to get property 'jenis_bahan' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Model of BahanLab

```
protected $table = 'bahan_labs';
protected $primaryKey = 'kode_bahan';
protected $fillable = ['kode_bahan', 'nama_bahan', 'kode_sinta', 'kode_jenis', 'harga_bahan', 'stok', 'satuan', 'minimum_stok'];
public $timestamps = false;

public function jenis()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\JenisBahan', 'kode_jenis');
}
```

Model of JenisBahan

```
protected $table = 'jenis_bahans';
protected $primaryKey = 'kode_jenis_bahan';
protected $fillable = ['kode_jenis_bahan', 'jenis_bahan'];
public $timestamps = false;

public function bahans()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\BahanLab');
}
```

I'm pretty sure that this is correct, I already define the relationship between these tables. But when I tried to do looping echo $bahan->jenis->jenis_bahan, it throws exception.

I already tried some suggestion to do dd($bahan->jenis->jenis_bahan) and I got null, so what is really happening?

## **UPDATE**

Controller:

```
$bahans = BahanLab::with('jenis')->get();
return view('bahan.daftar-bahan', compact('bahans'));
```

View:

```
<tbody>
@foreach($bahans as $bahan)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $bahan['kode_bahan'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ $bahan['nama_bahan'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ $bahan->jenis->jenis_bahan }}</td>
    <td>{{ $bahan['harga_bahan'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ $bahan['stok'] }} {{ $bahan['satuan'] }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looping, one of your `$bahan` objects doesn't have a `jenis` object (meaning `$bahan->jenis` is `null`, so you can't access `jenis_bahan` of a non-object, of which `null` is). To handle this, prevent loading `$bahans` unless it has a `jenis`, or check for it in the loop:

`Controller`:

```
$bahans = BahanLab::has('jenis')->with('jenis')->get();
return view('bahan.daftar-bahan', compact('bahans'));
```

Or, in your view:

```
<tbody>
@foreach($bahans as $bahan)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $bahan['kode_bahan'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ $bahan['nama_bahan'] }}</td>
    @if($bahan->jenis)
    <td>{{ $bahan->jenis->jenis_bahan }}</td>
    @else
    <td>No Jenis...</td>
    @endif
    <td>{{ $bahan['harga_bahan'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ $bahan['stok'] }} {{ $bahan['satuan'] }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Note: This `@if()` check is unnecessary if using `->has('jenis')`.

Also, you can use `->with()` and `->has()` together; `->has()` restricts the query results to those that have a `jenis` relationship, `->with()` eager loads it to increase performance in large datasets.

Comment: But this method works on my previous project. Is it because the primarykey or the foreignkey doesn't contain any 'id' text? My previous project has 'id' text both primary and foreign.

Comment: No, you've defined `kode_jenis` as the column that links `BahanLab` with `JenisBahan`. If you omitted that, then it likely would have looked for a `jenis_id` column. Does the code in my answer work? Or are you still having an issue?

Comment: $bahans = BahanLab::with('jenis')->has('jenis')->get(); Like this? It throws the same exception Trying to get property 'jenis_bahan' of non-object

Comment: Hmm... Sounds like your relationship isn't loading properly. But `has()` should prevent any `BahanLab` models from being loaded. Try to debug that; check your database and ensure you're using the right columns to link, they are populated, etc etc.

Comment: Tried to rename the primary key of BahanLab to id_bahan and JenisBahan to id_jenis and still the same error. So confused. Update: and foreignkey to jenis_id

Comment: You don't need to rename the columns in the database, just provide them in the relationship methods. Review https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many; `belongsTo()` and `hasMany()` can take up the 3 arguments, the model, the foreign key and the primary key.

Comment: You knew that I already did that, but still returns null :( return $this->belongsTo('App\JenisBahan', 'kode_jenis', 'kode_jenis_bahan');

Answer (score 0):

It's occured because my table I is a string, not an incremental Integer.
So to solve this problem, I just had to set

```
public $incrementing = false;
```